# Is there a way to unenroll students in LifterLMS when a subscription is cancelled in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write a php code to enable the system to unenroll students automatically when the user unsubscribes to a course in LifterLMS. This also means that they would not have to continue paying fees to WooCommerce. Is there any way I can do this? I wrote a php code to be added to functions.php but it is not working.

```
add_action( 'llms_unenroll_student', 'unenrol_when_cancelled' );
function unenrol_when_cancelled(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id);

    
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-cancelled' // Only orders with status "cancelled"
    ) );
    
    $subscriptionlist = [];
    foreach ($customer_orders as $subscription){
        $subscriptionlist[] = $subscription->get_id(); 
      }

    foreach ($subscriptionlist as $subscriptionid){
        if ($subscriptionid == '3400' || $subscriptionid == '74'){ 
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 7140, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 7099, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 6487, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 6388, $new_status, $trigger);

            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 7061, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 7014, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 5580, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 5167, $new_status, $trigger);

            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 6992, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 6962, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 6895, $new_status, $trigger);
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 6729, $new_status, $trigger);
        } elseif ($subscriptionid == '3136'){
            llms_unenroll_student($user_id, 5665, $new_status, $trigger);
        }
    }
}
```